# Do Microsoft provide an official, up to date (for 2018) reference for interfacing a windows service with Teams via a bot (avoiding Azure)?

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I appreciate that this question might look at first glance like it's off topic, but if you think it is, please read the paragraphs after the horizontal rule.

I'm seeking to create a windows service that performs some monitoring and alerting, and I'd like the alerts to be a Teams bot announcing to a channel

I'm thus looking for the current official reference material that outlines how to set about creating this. At the moment all I'm finding is Azure based stuff (don't want to create the bot in Azure - this has to be an on-machine app that chats in Teams) or things that seem to be old (recommending installation e.g. v3 of the Bot Framework, yet when I go to NPM in VS, I find v4).

Additionally, what I've read so far says that the bot needs to be registered somewhere (externally, with Microsoft/Azure?) before it will even work, though this registration can be private - when I say I want to avoid Azure, if this registration step is with some Azure based service and it's unavoidable then it will have to be thus; I'm just specifically aiming to avoid external services as much as possible

In summary my question is: where do I find the most up to date (for 2018) official (Microsoft blog or MSDN) guidance for connecting a C# windows forms/windows service based app to Teams, so it can use teams as an output channel for the results of its monitoring (or maybe accept commands and respond with monitoring results)?

---

Reference the close votes:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

This question is asking for a link to official documentation on a particular software provision/facility published by Microsoft. I don't see scope for opinion/spam on this - it's not a *"what's the best library to read an excel file without excel installed?"* and is thus free of opinion/cannot have spam answers; an answer either links to the current MS documentation or it doesn't.

I've kept closely to SO's mantra of "we prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed" - this question can definitely be answered. Either there is official documentation (where?) or there isn't (ok then)

*I've described the problem:*

I don't seem able to find the documentation I'm looking for

*I've described what has been done so far:*

I've read every resource I've turned up on google and haven't found anything that relates to the V4 Bot Framework SDK, API, or a set of docs pertaining to creating a bot outwith Azure

Comment: I think you can use incomingwebhook https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2016/11/03/use-webhook-connector-to-send-data-from-powershell-to-microsoft-teams/ this provide way to send message to a Teams Channel (and don't use Azure :) )but it's not supported to send ,notification to only 1 user

Comment: https://github.com/OfficeDev/TrainingContent/blob/master/Teams/02%20Connectors/Lab.md

Comment: You know SO isn´t the right place to ask for documentational ressources?

Comment: @HimBromBeere once upon a time SO had a tagline something like "the place where developers come to share and learn" - i don't remember the exact wording but it certainly wasn't "th place where developers come to be berated for asking for links to official documentation" and it's inconceivable that a good answer to something like "How do I format a datetime to a string?" would lack a link to MSDN, so I'm actually pretty sure that SO *IS* the right place to get advice and pointers to documentation..

Comment: You´re right and whrong at the same time. Indeed SO is for helping developers, but there are rules on how to ask for help, as seen on https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: In addition asking for "most recent" or "up to date" yields to answers that are "out of date" in two or three years and thus don´t help others coming here after some time.

Comment: I appreciate that, but at least there's a defined relevance-window built into the question, as well as the answers (time of posting is stated) and you're always free to leave a comment. In two or three years time, if the question is still being visited and commented, and the resource has changed, or the answer bettered, there are tools to manage it (old answers downvoted, newer better answers upvoted). I plan to not accept an answer to this question (though I'll upvoted the best answer for me) because accepting an answer overrides these temporal correction facilities..

Comment: Probably also worth noting that even a fact based question-answer pair will age and become irrelevant as new things come along, so everything that is "most recent" will never remain thus

Answer (score 4):

Please have a look at [Microsoft Teams concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/concepts-overview) documentaiton. [Office 365 Connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/connectors/connectors) are a great way to push your app's rich content into Microsoft Teams.

You can reach out to *Microsoft Teams developer support* alias mentioned in the [feedback documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback) for general questions.