# Sending automated messages to MS Teams channel using .NET 4.7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-teams

Was wondering if there were any tutorials on how to send messages to a MS Teams channel using a .NET Framework service? I've been looking at two different nuget packages Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams and Microsoft.Bot.Builder. Any suggestions would be a great help, thanks.

Comment: I[asked something similar once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52530935/do-microsoft-provide-an-official-up-to-date-for-2018-reference-for-interfacin) - didn't go down well. As it stands your question is off topic because it's asking us to recommend an off site resource or tutorial. You could perhaps phrase it as "what is the difference between package a and package b?" showing that you've done research but been unable to find out which package is applicable to your specific context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible to use the Bot approach, to send a "proactive" message (as it's called when the bot initiates the conversation, as opposed to just replying to a user). However, you haven't mentioned if you actually have a bot already?

If you do have a bot, I've given some guidance on sending the pro-active message at [Programmatically sending a message to a bot in Microsoft Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370644/programmatically-sending-a-message-to-a-bot-in-microsoft-teams/59439602#59439602).

If you *don't* have a bot already though, a more simple approach is just to use an [incoming webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook).

Comment: I don't have a bot but that link you posted about the incoming webhook seems to be what I'm looking for. Thanks!